# проблема с перемещением обьекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня есть скрипт врага

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health;
    public float speed;
    public GameObject effect;
    private Player player;

    private void Start()
    {
        player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

        public void TakeDamage(int damage)
     {
    health -= damage;
     }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

и он по идее должен преследовать игрока и убивать при касании, но он встает в позицию ниже слева и преследует оттуда...
[image: ..]

Comment: И что с ним не так? Время два ночи и экстрасенсы уже спят

Comment: он на скрине и есть в той позиции, и просто остается в ней

Answer (score -1):

перенес игрока в 0 коордианты и все заработало.